# FoxPro how to accomplish equivalent to Excel ROUNDUP and ROUNDDOWN

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am hoping to accomplish the equivalent of Microsoft Excel's ROUNDUP and ROUNDDOWN functions. Right now I am using the following:

```
roundup_val = ROUND(val + 0.005,2)
```

which will round up a **positive value** to the second decimal place since 0.005 is being added to the value. However, this does not work correctly if the value only has 2 decimal places or left. For example, Excel's ROUNDUP to 2 decimal places on a value, val = 20.01, will return the same value, ROUNDUP(20.01,2) = 20.01. My method above will return ROUND(20.015,2) = 20.02, which is incorrect.

I think this method will work if I include more code to check wether the number has less than three decimal places and then it will simply keep the same number since it is already rounded to the second place. If I'm to do this, I was also wondering how I can check how many decimal places long a number is.

It is also possible that this method is not the best way to accomplish a FoxPro version of ROUNDUP. Are there any other ideas out there that will work on all numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - why do you think ROUND(20.015,2) = 20.02 is incorrect? If you do this in Excel it will give 20.02 as well. It’s not clear, to me, what your issue is

Comment: @NickW, round(20.015,2) = 20.02 is correct and in Excel's RoundUp() it would also return 20.02. However, he is trying to use it to return like Excel's ROUNDUP(20.01,2) = 20.01 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right VFP doesn't have RoundUp() and RoundDown() functions. But they are very easy to create. I had this already at my backyard:

```
*ROUNDUP.PRG
Lparameters tnValue, tnPlaces
Local lnResult, lnValue
lnValue = Abs(m.tnValue)
If Round(m.lnValue, m.tnPlaces) != m.lnValue
    lnValue = Round(m.lnValue+((10^-(m.tnPlaces+1))*5), m.tnPlaces)
EndIf
Return Sign(m.tnValue) * m.lnValue

*ROUNDDOWN.PRG
Lparameters tnValue, tnPlaces
Local lnResult, lnValue
lnValue = Abs(m.tnValue)
If Round(m.lnValue, m.tnPlaces) != m.lnValue
    lnValue = Round(m.lnValue-((10^-(m.tnPlaces+1))*5), m.tnPlaces)
EndIf
Return Sign(m.tnValue) * m.lnValue
```

Just save these as roundup.prg and rounddown.prg, and you have ROUNDUP(), ROUNDDOWN() functions as Excel's.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `CEILING` and `FLOOR` functions:

- The `CEILING` of a number is the next integer greater than or equal to the number.
- The `FLOOR` of a number is the next integer less than or equal to the number.

```
? CEILING(3.14159)  && 4
? FLOOR(3.14159)    && 3
? CEILING(-17.385)  && -17
? FLOOR(-17.385)    && -18
```

Extract from: https://hackfox.github.io/section4/s4g050.html